# Encoding C Structs

Tags: cocoa

I have a struct defined like follows as part of an object. I'm trying to encode this for use with NSCoder with the aim of saving as well as Undo/Redo functionality.

```
struct myCol {
    float rd;
    float grn;
    float blu;
    float alp;
} toolColor;
```

So, there are methods to encode e.g. `-encodeBool:`, `-encodeFloat:`, `-encodeObject:` etc. But how do you do this for a struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should consider you struct myCol as memory buffer and encode it by something like **encodeBytes** function. Buffer length = size of your struct

Comment: You can either do it like this, as macropas says, or you can wrap it in an NSValue object.

Comment: Thanks guys. Since an object is required I decided to use NSColor instead of struct. I guess I should have in the first place! But I'm learning.

Comment: Actually, wrapping a struct in a plain NSValue *doesn't* make it encodable. Just learned this the hard way. Details why are in the apple docs, "Archives and Serializations Programming Guide for Cocoa", "Encoding and Decoding C Data Types". 

I made my own category similar to NSValue(NSValueUIGeometryExtensions) and it works great; but I've not yet found a way to add one paralleling NSCoder(UIGeometryKeyedCoding) and have it be used, short of subclassing NSValue.

Comment: Going the encodeBytes route is fine provided that data will never move between 32 and 64 bit devices. Now that the 5s is a 64bit device, I believe you'll run into major issues if that data is say, synced with iCloud and then brought from a 32bit device to a 64bit device. The only reliable way is individually encoding each data type as you go...  i'm actually hoping this isn't the case, so if anyone disagrees please respond!